# smooth curve has measure zero in $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: real-analysis

Problem says:

> Let $u:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ be a smooth curve. Prove that in
>   $\mathbb R^3$, $N:=u([0,1])$ has measure zero.

I found more general result as follow:

Sard's theorem says:

> If $f:M\rightarrow N$ is a smooth map, and $C$ is the set of all point
>   critical points of $f$ in $M$. Then $f(C)$ is a measure zero set in N.

And one of its corollary says:

> If $f:M\rightarrow N$ is smooth and $\dim M<\dim N $, then $f(M)$ has
>   measure zero.

So, by applying it, $N$ in the problem has measure zero. But problem is proving the corollary.

Comment: The word "smooth" can be context dependent.  Does your source specify a meaning, for example "piecewise continuously differentiable with finitely many pieces"?

Comment: The corollary is trivial: how can your map have rank equal to the dimension of your target space, if your domain has dimension strictly less? Hence every point is critical

Comment: @EricTowers Actually, the smoothness used in my textbook means $C^\infty $

Comment: @b00nheT Okay, I see. Then Is is okay to say that corollary proves my problem?

Comment: Yes, most definitely. By the way: You can find a simpler proof avoiding Sard, on page 18 of this script http://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/fs2016/math/dg2/diffGeomI_notes.pdf See Remark 1.44 (i)